# How do I set the default value of a <select> element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a plain old `<select>` element that iterates through a list of options:

```
<select onChange={(event) => this.setState({selectedOption: event.target.value }) }>
{
    this.state.options.map(option => <option key={option.label} value={option.value}>{option.value}</option>)
}
</select>
```

Since I'm fetching the list of options and the selected item is being fetched via AJAX, I'm doing this -- but it doesn't work either:

```
<option key={option.label} selected={option.value === this.state.selectedOption} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
```

How do I set the default option (without using an external library, creating custom component)?

Edit: `options` is just a list of objects:

```
[
    {label: 'foo', value: 'fooValue'},
    {label: 'bar', value: 'barValue'},
]
```

Comment: What is the default value of `this.state.selectedOption`?

Comment: @MelvinAbraham It's just a string.

Comment: I know the data type of `selectedOption` but what is the value of this state variable (like is it **"default"** or **"1"**, etc.) when the component is rendered initially?

Comment: Initially, it's set to an empty string. During `componentDidMount` it is set to a value in `options` list (e.g. 'fooValue').

Comment: The documentation has an [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag) of how to handle `select` elements that it would be worth looking at. Using that method, your initial state is the initial/default value.

Answer (score 1):

All defaults can be set in the constructor...

```
class ComponentName extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(props);
        this.state = { selectedOption: "My Default Select Value" }
    }
}
```

After that, let's look at your `onChange` handler, which is setup well here: you are correctly setting the state to the value of selected option.  Assuming that this is JSX that gets returned from `render()`, then the only thing you are missing is to set the `value` attribute of the component...

```
<select
    value={this.state.selectedOption}
    onChange={(event) => this.setState({selectedOption: event.target.value }) }
>
{
    this.state.options.map(option => <option key={option.label} value={option.value}>{option.value}</option>)
}
</select>
```

Take a look at the official docs (Source: [**ReactJS.org: Forms**](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag))...

> React, instead of using this selected attribute, uses a value attribute on the root select tag. This is more convenient in a controlled component because you only need to update it in one place.
>
> ```
> Pick your favorite flavor:
> <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `selected` attribute is not working is probably because the default value of `this.state.selectedOption` is not set. In order to fix this, you can set the value of `selectedOption` within the constructor.

```
class ComponentName extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        ...
        this.state = { selectedOption: "<default_option>" }
        ...
    }
}
```

In case you don't know the default value that should be set beforehand, then, you can use `setState()` later to change the value of `selectedOption`.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-feynman-1b6g1?file=/src/App.js

```
function myAjaxFunction(...) {
    let default_value = ...

    this.setState({
        selectedOption: default_value
    });

    ...
}
```

*PS: This answer assumes that you are using class-based component.*

Comment: @3limin4t0r It can be done separately but in this case it's going work just fine. Since after the options update, the component will re-render, the `selected` attribute will get updated automatically.